# Optimizing python code into one return statement

Tags: python, optimization, average

I figured out how to do a certain task, but it required me to create and define two entirely separate functions. I want to just have that original function and just one return statement, but I can't figure out how to do it.

What I have:

```
def fp_golden_ratio_avgdamp(): 
    return fp(avgdamp(lambda x: 1 + 1/x), 1.0)

def avgdamp(f):
    return lambda x: avg(float(x), f(x))

def avg(x, y):
    return (x + y) / 2.0
```

which when you call `fp_golden_ratio_avgdamp()` prints:

```
(25, 1.6180339887498754)
```

The `fp` function is something that works a 100% and it accepts `lambda x: 1 + 1/x` and a set value of 1.0 as some error point, which prints

```
(32, 1.6180339887499087)
```

So what I'm trying to pass in to that fp function is something that goes through the other two function first.

My attempt at this was:

```
def fp_golden_ratio_avgdamp():
    return fp( lambda x:( ((float(1 + 1/x) + (1 + 1/x)) / 2.0) ) , 1.0)
```

But this resulted in the same thing as if I were to do

```
return fp(lambda x: 1 + 1/x, 1.0)
```

Which prints this:

```
(32, 1.6180339887499087)
```

So to summarize my question: I want to get rid of the `avgdamp` and `avg` functions and just optimize it to be a one liner.

```
def fp_golden_ratio_avgdamp(): 
    return fp( '''do something with this (lambda x: 1 + 1/x) that is the same computation of the avgdamp and avg functions''', 1.0)
```

Can someone help me out?

Comment: Why does it need to be a *one-liner*?

Comment: He wants us to be one, but I spent hours trying to figure it out, but i couldn't without creating two separate functions.

Comment: Is this a homework excercise?

Comment: @wwii: It's a function passed in as parameter.  However, it's unclear what `fp()` in the first function is.

Comment: f is the variable being passed into the avgdamp function

Comment: fp is a fixed_point function that should work for other functions in this assignment, which i got from notes in the class

Comment: @ChappyKhmao BTW, when you're writing real code, *never* spend hours trying to compress code down to one line. That almost always hurts readability.

Comment: @Carcigenicate sorry about that, I really have a hard time with, fill in the blank coding assignments, I wish he would just let us code how we would want it.

Comment: @ChappyKhmao No need to apologize. Just letting you know. Don't think that one liners are necessarily better than larger pieces of code.

Comment: @Carcigenicate ok thanks for the advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going through this incrementally:

```
def avgdamp(f):
    return lambda x: avg(float(x), f(x))

def avg(x, y):
    return (x + y) / 2.0
```

This can be easily put into one function:

```
def avgdamp(f):
    return lambda x: (float(x) + f(x)) / 2.0
```

Now this should be combined with `fp_golden_ratio_avgdamp`:

```
def fp_golden_ratio_avgdamp(): 
    return fp(avgdamp(lambda x: 1 + 1/x), 1.0)
```

So `avgdamp` get's one argument that's a function and it's applied on the second value so we need to apply the original function there:

```
def fp_golden_ratio_avgdamp(): 
    return fp((lambda x: (float(x) + 1 + 1/x) / 2.0), 1.0)
```

---

Note that you applied your `1+1/x` function on both values:

```
return fp( lambda x:( ((float(1 + 1/x) + (1 + 1/x)) / 2.0) ) , 1.0)
```

that's a problem because `((float(1 + 1/x) + (1 + 1/x)) = 2 * (1 + 1 / x)` (if `x` is a float) and then the average is simply: `(1+1/x)`.

Comment: thank you very much!!! you just summarized what i've been trying to do hours ago in only a matter of mins.